# How to rename _id field after mongo's group aggregation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to get the revenue for each month using aggregation,

code snippet to get monthly revenue:

```
const getTotal = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {


  const monthly = await Order.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        createdAt: {
          $gte: moment().startOf("year").toDate(),
          $lte: moment().endOf("yaer").toDate(),
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: { $month: "$createdAt" },
        Total: { $sum: "$price" },
      },
    },
  ]);

  res.status(200).json(monthly);
});
```

here is the result in Postman

```
[
   {
        "_id": 1,
        "Total": 4843
    },
    {
        "_id": 2,
        "Total": 4843
    },
    {
        "_id": 3,
        "Total": 2000
    },
   ....
    {
        "_id": 8,
        "Total": 3658
    },
    {
        "_id": 9,
        "Total": 620
    }
]
```

so my question is: how can i rename _id field after mongo's group aggregation to "name"?

and how can i change month number to month name ?

the desired output :

```
[
   {
        "name": "Jan",
        "Total": 4843
    },
    {
        "name": "Feb",
        "Total": 4843
    },
    {
        "name": "Mar,
        "Total": 2000
    },
   ....
    {
        "name": "Aug,
        "Total": 3658
    },
    {
        "name": "Sep,
        "Total": 620
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rename the `_id` field to `name` and change the month number to the month name in your MongoDB aggregation result, you can use the `$addFields` stage to add a new field based on the value of _id. You can also use the `$switch` operator to map the month number to the month name. Here's how you can modify your aggregation pipeline to achieve this:

```
const getTotal = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const monthly = await Order.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        createdAt: {
          $gte: moment().startOf("year").toDate(),
          $lte: moment().endOf("year").toDate(),
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: { $month: "$createdAt" },
        Total: { $sum: "$price" },
      },
    },
    {
      $addFields: {
        name: {
          $switch: {
            branches: [
              { case: 1, then: "Jan" },
              { case: 2, then: "Feb" },
              { case: 3, then: "Mar" },
              { case: 4, then: "Apr" },
              { case: 5, then: "May" },
              { case: 6, then: "Jun" },
              { case: 7, then: "Jul" },
              { case: 8, then: "Aug" },
              { case: 9, then: "Sep" },
              { case: 10, then: "Oct" },
              { case: 11, then: "Nov" },
              { case: 12, then: "Dec" },
            ],
            default: "Unknown",
          },
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0, // Exclude the original _id field
      },
    },
  ]);

  res.status(200).json(monthly);
});
```

And from @Wernfried Domscheit, you can use `$$REMOVE`

```
const getTotal = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const monthly = await Order.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        createdAt: {
          $gte: moment().startOf("year").toDate(),
          $lte: moment().endOf("year").toDate(),
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: { $month: "$createdAt" },
        Total: { $sum: "$price" },
      },
    },
    {
      $addFields: {
        name: {
          $switch: {
            branches: [
              { case: 1, then: "Jan" },
              { case: 2, then: "Feb" },
              { case: 3, then: "Mar" },
              { case: 4, then: "Apr" },
              { case: 5, then: "May" },
              { case: 6, then: "Jun" },
              { case: 7, then: "Jul" },
              { case: 8, then: "Aug" },
              { case: 9, then: "Sep" },
              { case: 10, then: "Oct" },
              { case: 11, then: "Nov" },
              { case: 12, then: "Dec" },
            ],
            default: "Unknown",
          },
        },
        _id: "$$REMOVE", // Remove the original _id field
      },
    },
  ]);

  res.status(200).json(monthly);
});
```

Comment: You can remove `_id` field also with `_id: "$$REMOVE"`, then you have one stage less.

Comment: it work as expected but it return only "Jan" for name field ,like this: [
    {
        "Total": 3658,
        "name": "Jan"
    },
    {
        "Total": 620,
        "name": "Jan"
    }
]

Comment: I fix it using { $eq: [ "$_id", 1 ] }

Comment: { case: { $eq: [ "$_id", 6 ] }, then: "Jun" },